# Video have sound but no image in Chrome, Edge & Firefox

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I am working on a WordPress website and facing a major issues with some of my self hosted videos. I am uploading videos to wordpress media Library and playing them using Easy video player in my posts. There are some video with only audio. I tried those in different browsers and they work fine in UC Mini on Android. Chrome, Edge & Firefox are just playing the audio on both PC & mobile versions.

Please help me get rid of this issue.
Shall be thankful
[you can check sample here](https://todaysflix.com/episode/episode-1-9/)

Answer (score 0):

your video is encoded as MPEG4 - part 2. this is a really old format. I'd recommend re-encoding the video as mp4 using the h264 codec.

At an hour long - you might also want to consider adaptive bitrate streaming - to allow for different screen sizes and varying network conditions.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i will encode it again with h264 format. 'At an hour long - you might also want to consider adaptive bitrate streaming - to allow for different screen sizes and varying network conditions.'
I didn't get this point, can you please explain it to me and guide me to how can i do that.

Comment: Netflix does not send down a mp4.  It encodes the video into HLS, and they use adaptive bitrate streaming.  This allows the video player to automatically adapt to the player size, and network speed.  small screens get a smaller sized video, big screens get a bigger video.  More details: https://api.video/what-is/adaptive-bitrate-streaming